# Inconsistent attribute reference in `exists?` method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my `User` model:

```
class User
  def upcoming_events_in(minutes, client_id)
    events.where(client_id: client_id).exists?(start: (Time.zone.now - duration)..(Time.zone.now + minutes))
  end
end
```

In method `upcoming_events_in`, it correctly looks for `start` attribute on the `events` record, but it attempts to look for `duration` on the `User` instance. Is there a way to tie it to the `events` instance?

Comment: `duration` is confusing me. Where `duration` is defined? I mean, I suppose I should use something like `start_time` to find upcoming events.

Comment: I guess the method name is confusing over here. `duration` is the duration of the event. My main problem is how to ensure that it looks for `duration` on `event` record rather than `user` record

Comment: You cannot perform the query in this fashion because the range needs to be interpreted prior to being translated to SQL you cannot mix and match the ruby code with database specific logic.

Comment: _"it attempts to look for `duration` in the user instance"_ - It is because your method `upcoming_events_in` is defined in `User` class and (you haven't cleared what `duration` refers to in your method) i assume `duration` is some attribute or method from `User` class itself.

Comment: I can't find a way following your idea. But maybe you can evaluate something like this: `events.where(client_id: client_id).select(:start_time, :duration).to_a.delete_if { |event| ![Time.zone.now - event.duration..Time.zone.now + minutes].include? event.start_time }.any?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea about `Rails` but it can be easily performed with plain old good SQL:

```
def upcoming_events_in(minutes, client_id)
  events.
    where(client_id: client_id).
    where('DATEDIFF(events.start, DATESUB(NOW(), INTERVAL events.duration MINUTES)) > 0').
    where('DATEDIFF(events.start, DATEADD(NOW(), INTERVAL events.minutes MINUTES)) < 0').
    exists?
end
```

---

*PostgreSQL* version:

```
def upcoming_events_in(minutes, client_id)
  start = "(TIMESTAMP events.start, TIMESTAMP events.start + INTERVAL '1 MINUTE')"
  interval = "(NOW() - INTERVAL 'events.duration MINUTES', NOW() + INTERVAL 'events.minutes MINUTES')"

  events.
    where(client_id: client_id).
    where("#{start} OVERLAPS #{interval}").
    exists?
end
```

Or like, I don’t have PG to check.

Comment: I get the following error on using the above: `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "30"` where 30 is the value for the `minutes` argument

Comment: Oh, you do use `Postgres`. It makes sense to mention it upfront. I will update an answer accordingly.